# Pass command line argument in NUnit class library type project in Visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit, command-line-arguments

I have a `NUnit` visual studio test project `class library` type ,I need to pass `command line` argument  in to project and access that argument.

When i have create another `class library` type project then i am able to take argument into `Main` function.

But the `Nunit test project` have not entry point or `Main` function.How to do that scenario.

Please help.

Comment: You sure you want to do this? It probably falls prey to taking a dependency on something external. However, take a look at [Environment.GetCommandLineArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189149/pass-parameters-via-command-line-to-nunit

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen : it gives the following `{string[3]}
    [0]: "C:\\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\\COMMON7\\IDE\\COMMONEXTENSIONS\\MICROSOFT\\TESTWINDOW\\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe"
    [1]: "/parentProcessId"
    [2]: "7788"` . But I have defined only `AA` in command line argument.

Comment: Command line arguments aren't passed from Visual Studio to the test runner, they will only work if you start the test runner manually. My advice, find a different way to do whatever it is you want done.

Comment: Please suggest the other way. I am executing the test dll from nunit command exe and need some config value pass into test project and use.