# how to send parameter to a dll with nunit command?

Tags: dll, nunit

I run through console a **myProgram.dll** with **NUnit**. I'd like the **myProgram.dll** I coded to receive a specific date which is a date to stop.

```
nunit-console myProgram.dll
```

I know I could achieve it by writing the date to stop in a text file and my function `[Test]` could read in the document. But is there a more direct way?

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3189149/pass-parameters-via-command-line-to-nunit

Comment: I think that may answer it, thx! I want to post a detailed answer, what I would do is : nunit-console myProgram.dll set "bobby" ? that doesn't work maybe I misuse it